# Azure service bus subscription - receive and delete for multiple messages

Tags: azureservicebus

I am working on REST API, for receiving the messages from Azure service bus subscription.
The problem is that I am able to receive the messages individually from the subscription using the HTTP calls, however, I want to receive the messages from service bus in batches (say 100, 200, 1000..) so that I save the HTTP call and make the logic more efficient.

I am referring to following link for ASB..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read

Is there any such setting to receive the messages in bulk (and delete them). Tried searching, didnt find anything useful in this context. Please help.

Comment: It is not possible to receive batches using the Service Bus REST API, but you can do so using the SDK, why do you know to use REST ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to receive batches through Service Bus REST API, however you can use the [SB SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessor?view=azure-dotnet) to process those, do yo have a requirement to use a HTTP client ? if not, then use the SDK